# Android GoogleMapV2 Current Location Not working

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I was trying to take Current location using android google map v2.My App is crashing...My code and logcat is follows.I searched a lot to get it.Please get rid of it.

```
setContentView(R.layout.location_map);
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
googleMap = fm.getMap();
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
double currentlatitude = location.getLatitude();
double currentlongitude = location.getLongitude();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
CURRENT_LOCATION = new LatLng(currentlatitude, currentlongitude);
```

My Log cat is follows

```
04-24 17:58:33.681: I/x(17640): Making Creator dynamically
04-24 17:58:33.691: W/dalvikvm(17640): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar'
04-24 17:58:33.711: I/Google Maps Android API(17640): Google Play services client version: 6587000
04-24 17:58:33.721: I/Google Maps Android API(17640): Google Play services package version: 7329032
04-24 17:58:33.922: D/AbsListView(17640): Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-24 17:58:34.172: I/dalvikvm(17640): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.hg.a
04-24 17:58:34.172: W/dalvikvm(17640): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 449: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
04-24 17:58:34.172: D/dalvikvm(17640): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
04-24 17:58:34.212: D/AndroidRuntime(17640): Shutting down VM
04-24 17:58:34.212: W/dalvikvm(17640): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b53c08)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640): Process: com.ambilobes.flowbornprivilege, PID: 17640
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ambilobes.flowbornprivilege/com.ambilobes.flowbornprivilege.LocationFinder}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1305)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5598)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at com.ambilobes.flowbornprivilege.LocationFinder.onCreate(LocationFinder.java:61)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5459)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
04-24 17:58:34.222: E/AndroidRuntime(17640):    ... 11 more
04-24 18:03:34.285: I/Process(17640): Sending signal. PID: 17640 SIG: 9
04-24 18:03:34.665: E/Qmage(17959): onDecode : QmageDecodeFrame 20140421
```

Comment: If your requirement is only to find location, you don't need to use Google Maps v2

Comment: @ Jayesh Elamgodi I need to use mapv2 plse tell me

Comment: `getLastKnownLocation()` can readily return `null`. You are not checking for `null` and handling that case.

Comment: If igetLastKnownLocation() is getting null then how can i get current location

Answer (score 0):

This apparently has nothing to do with Google Map v2 API...

> RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ambilobes.flowbornprivilege/com.ambilobes.flowbornprivilege.LocationFinder}: java.lang.NullPointerException

You got yourself  `NullPointerException`. Let's see about it:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at com.ambilobes.flowbornprivilege.LocationFinder.onCreate(LocationFinder.java:61)

Look at **LocationFinder.java:61** and you'll find your problem.

Comment: I am not getting current latitude on line 61 . You can see that line above

Comment: Android nor I never said you were. Logcat says you're getting an Exception... Would you mind posting the code? And if you did, would you mind telling us which line is line 61?..

Comment: double currentlatitude = location.getLatitude(); line 61

Comment: Ok @Javad, the Logcat and I are telling you that on this line 61 `double currentlatitude = location.getLatitude();`, `location` is actually `null`.

Comment: `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider)` returns a `null` location. If no last known location was available, you should check for it to be `null` before processing it. Google Maps API v2 works fine.